# moodle : How is parent/child mentor/mentee role relationship stored?

Tags: moodle

How or where does moodle store how a parent/mentor is related to a student.  I don't see how the system is tying the user and role assignment and whatever else it's using (context, etc). 
I jut want to be able to query for a list of users who have supervisor/parent role and get their corresponding students.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have configured the parent role as defined here: https://docs.moodle.org/en/Parent_role

If so, the connection is as follows:

Each user has a 'context' record, related to their userid. This can be retrieved via context_user::instance($userid) or from the database by

```
SELECT * 
FROM mdl_context
WHERE instanceid = [userid] AND contextlevel = 30
```

(Where 30 is CONTEXT_USER and assuming your DB prefix is the default 'mdl_')

Parent/mentors have an appropriate role assigned to them at this user's context.

You can find this in the database by the following query:

```
SELECT userid
FROM mdl_role_assignments
WHERE contextid = [usercontextid]
```

Optionally, this could be restricted to only retrieve specific roleids (with "AND roleid = [parentroleid]"). However, most sites will only have parent/mentor roles assigned in the user context, so you can probably get away without checking the roleid.

Comment: Thanking you davosmith.

Yes you are right I have configured the role as defined here https://docs.moodle.org/en/Parent_role

Actually I have integrated Moodle with Wordpress and In my portal student/parent they get registered in wordpress also student can enter his details and his parent details as well. both the account gets generated in both wordpress and moodle.

So we want to configured parent_id with student in Moodle at the time of successful registration instead of configuring manually. we want dynamically configured in Moodle.

your suggestion would help us....!!!
Thanks

Comment: This helped me on my way to finding what I was looking for, which was actually this that I found on the Moodle forums: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=199269#p880308

Answer (score 0):

The following query will perfectly answer your parent child relationship.

This query will return the parent id when you will pass the child id in query

```
SELECT userid as parent FROM mdl_role_assignments
join mdl_context on mdl_context.id = mdl_role_assignments.contextid 
where mdl_context.contextlevel = 30 and mdl_context.instanceid = 162
```

here 162 is the child id